# LXDE autostart takes too long to start chromium-browser

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, chromium, lxde

I am trying to start chromium-browser via `~/.config/LXDE-pi/autostart`. The command is as follows:

```
@chromium-browser localhost/scada --kiosk --incognito
```

The problem I am having is that it takes exactly 2 minutes and 30 seconds from the moment the desktop appears to the moment the browser window opens, which seems a bit too long. I feel like there's a timeout of some sort that has to happen first...

On top of that, it looks like VNC launch is also affected by it.

Any ideas on how to speed up or troubleshoot the delay?

Thanks!

Update: LXDE run.log errors:

```
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/usr/share/lxde/openbox/menu.xml"
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml"
: getrandom indicates that the entropy pool has not been initialized. Rather than continue with poor entropy, this process will block until entropy is available.
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
[899:1061:0108/193549.450074:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[992:992:0108/193549.567951:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(364)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9481
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9599
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9637
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9675
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9713
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9751
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9789
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9827
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9865
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9903
error 140: BadRegion request 138 minor 14 serial 9941
[899:1264:0108/203703.085322:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(42)] Out of memory.
Trace/breakpoint trap
 --disable-quic --enable-tcp-fast-open --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version=
error 3: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) request 142 minor 6 serial 437165
error 9: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) request 139 minor 4 serial 437166
error 4: BadPixmap (invalid Pixmap parameter) request 54 minor 0 serial 437235
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
[1943:2047:0108/203711.590524:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[1996:1996:0108/203713.619228:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(364)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[1943:1988:0108/213844.016484:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(42)] Out of memory.
Trace/breakpoint trap
 --disable-quic --enable-tcp-fast-open --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version=
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
[2867:2971:0108/213852.645707:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(621)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[2920:2920:0108/213854.648608:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(364)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
error 3: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) request 15 minor 0 serial 876247
```

Comment: I have been waiting a couple of years, since Rpi 1 when there was no Chrome, even slow version. Before every version they, the RF engineers said they are working hard to move Chrome faster. But even with Rpi4B 2GB, Chrome is still unbearably slow, starting up or working. So every version I was disappointed and go back to the my evil Wintel10PC6GBCorei5NivdiaGeforce. Now I am anxiously waiting for the hopefully faster Rpi5B+ Chrome. By the way, I heard that Rpi Chrome is not using the GPU, therefore so slow. If that is so, then I need not wasting my time waiting any longer.

Comment: It's not the browser itself, It's something before it that delays the execution of autostart file, and, in fact, also delays VNC launch too. The browser itself loads in about 2 seconds.

Comment: Ah, I am terribly sorry that I did not read your question carefully. So your problem is not on the browser, but on autostart file and VNC launch. I forgot to ask if you are using Rpi2/3 which are slower than Rpi4B. Just now I tried to start Chromium and visit a site.  I very surprisingly found that Chromium STARTED IN LESS THAN 10 SECONDS, and visited a busy SITE also in less than 10 seconds. So I have wrongly accusing the RF engineers. I am not sure if my bad experience was because I was running too many apps at the same time, and my 2GB RAM was full and need to do time wasting swapping, ...

Comment: To confirm my wrong accusation on RF and Rpi, just now I closed the Chromium, restarted and visited apple.com. As you said, both starting Chromium and go to apple.com takes less than 2 seconds. The Chromium's English to Chinese translation is as fast.  I have no more protests to RF, Rpi, and Chromium.  My big apologies to them all. :)

Comment: Could you check `/home/pi/.xsession-errors` for errors?

Comment: @FlippingBinary, nothing there, but points to `~./cashe/lxsession/LXDE-pi/run.log` , that has some errors, but I don't think they are related (see above). Any other log to check?

Comment: @Ephemeral, just did, memory errors gone (thanks!), but boot speed is the same, didn't hange at all.